# How to custom sort a one dimensional javascript array by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a javascript array looking like this:

```
[USD: -119, EUR: 217, TRY: -401, GBP: 200, AED: 700]
```

And I want to sort it as below:

```
[USD: -119, TRY: -401, EUR: 217, AED: 700, GBP: 200]
```

Keeping in mind that these arrays are created dynamically, so some of them can have no GBP for example or EUR, or in one array for example EUR can appear at 3th place or at the end.

Comment: What is the logic for such a sort order?

Comment: What is this sort based on? Without any context this seems kind of random.

Comment: On what logical basis are these sorted by? It doesn't appear to be by key nor by value. BTW, I don't think that's syntactically correct to be an array in JavaScript.

Comment: So basically I have many currencies and the sort I want is as follows: USD, TRY, EUR, AED, GBP

Comment: Do you have an associative array or an object? If it is an array, why aren't you using an object? Adding custom keys to arrays isn't a good idea.

Comment: @adiga can be both, if you have a solution for an object with the same structure then it would be nice

Comment: @ershad7 You should have a currency order list by which you want to order

Comment: If you just replace those square brackets `[]` with curly brackets `{}` it will be an object literal. The order of keys won't matter then because you simply call on a value like so: `var object = { USD: -119, TRY: -401, EUR: 217, AED: 700, GBP: 200 };` `object.AED` would return the value of 700.

Comment: @zer00ne but I am doing foreach on these, just as I said they are generated dynamically and I don't know which one has AED or which don't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of strings given a predefined order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274505/sort-a-list-of-strings-given-a-predefined-order)

Comment: @ershad7 when you iterate through a data structure, you don't need prior knowledge of content if you prepare for the possibility of said content existing. What you have is malformed, JavaScript rejects it because it expects an array to have no unquoted semi-colons.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create an array with the desired order. Then you use the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function. To compare elements, compare which has the higher/lower index in the sortOrder array.

```js
const sortOrder = ['USD', 'TRY', 'EUR', 'AED', 'GBP']
const data = [['USD', -119], ['EUR', 217], ['TRY', -401], ['GBP', 200], ['AED', 700]]
console.log(data.sort((a, b) => sortOrder.indexOf(a[0]) - sortOrder.indexOf(b[0])))
```

Comment: Can I ask why you made the original array nested?

Comment: You didn't specify what the input should be. The "javascript array" you provided is not valid javascript, it looks like a mixture of array and object So I just took an array because it should have an order, and made it nested because I somehow need to group `'USD'` with `-119`. You can choose a different inner structure though

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any comparison logic, this is not sorting, this is basically the order you want specifically in the array.

I'd suggest creating a new array, checking if an item of the specific location exists, if yes, add it to the new array.

This is crucial if you say that keys are created dynamically, and there is no prior knowledge of the contents of the array.

```
let oldArray = {USD: -119, EUR: 217, TRY: -401, GBP: 200, AED: 700};
let newArray = {};
if (oldArray['USD']) {
    newArray['USD'] = oldArray['USD'];    
}
if (oldArray['TRY']) {
    newArray['TRY'] = oldArray['TRY'];
}
if (oldArray['EUR']) {
    newArray['EUR'] = oldArray['EUR'];
}
if (oldArray['AED']) {
    newArray['AED'] = oldArray['AED'];
}
if (oldArray['GBP']) {
    newArray['GBP'] = oldArray['GBP'];
}
console.log(newArray);
```